# Are polynomials with only real zeros log concave functions?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

In this [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229028/log-concave-polynomial-is-a-log-concave-function), [Richard Stanley](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2807/richard-stanley) mentions that polynomials with only real roots are log concave functions. Can somebody provide a reference for this result? I can't find it anywhere. I am in particular interested to know if the result holds for polynomials in more than one dimension.

Also, does anybody know other results about the log-concavity of polynomials as functions?

(To be clear I'm not talking about log-concave polynomials in the sense that their coefficients form a log-concave sequence.)

Comment: Did you try using Vieta's formulas?

Comment: Have a look at : (https://joshalman.quora.com/Polynomials-with-Real-Roots-have-Ultra-Log-Concave-Coefficients-and-an-Application-to-Flipping-Coins)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I'm not sure how Vieta's would helps. Do you have something in mind?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks but this mentions that the polynomial's coefficients form a log-concave sequence. I'm interested in the log-concavity of the polynomial as a function.

Comment: That's not what was implied by Stanley's comment.

Comment: The initial question was about log-concave polynomials also being log-concave functions so I thought Stanley's comments was the same. It's not perfectly clear, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to outline possible two ways.

Method 1: Note, this only works when $p$ has negative roots. Then the coefficients of $p$ are positive. We know by Newton's Inequalities that these coefficients form an ultra log-concave sequence. Hence, by Shephard's Theorem (1960), we can realize $p$ as the relative Steiner polynomial $\text{Vol}(K + xL) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} W_{k}(K;L) x^{k}$ of two convex bodies $K,L$. From there, the Brunn-Minkowski Inequality gives you log-concavity of $p$ as a univariate function of $x$.

Method 2: Use the fact that the roots of $p'$ interlacing the roots of $p$ (this is a consequence of the Mean-Value Theorem applied to the intervals $(\lambda_{i},\lambda_{i+1})$ where $\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n}$ are the roots of $p$). Then use Lemma 10.21 from [a lecture note by Shayan O. Gharan](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~shayan/courses/cse599/adv-approx-10.pdf) on $p$ and $p'$. Note the Wronskian $W[p,p'] = p \cdot p'' - (p')^{2}$ is just the numerator of the second derivative of $\log p(x)$ (its denominator is $p^{2}$). Then use the fact that log-concavity of a function is equivalent to nonpositivity of the second derivative of $\log p(x)$. (Sorry I'm a bit lazy to type out the proof of Lemma 10.21 here).

Best wishes.

EDIT: I embarrassingly realized there is an extremely elementary method, which is just to write $p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (x - \lambda_{i})$ and then observe that $\log p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log (x - \lambda_{i})$. The summation of concave functions is concave and it isn't difficult to verify that each $\log (x - \lambda_{i})$ is concave on their appropriate domain of definition.

Comment: (+1) I really enjoyed the first two overkills!